# Forming word combinations from file

Tags: optimization, c, cryptography

I am looking for ideas to optimize the below code for speed.  I'm also looking for some good improvement in execution time.

This code reads a text file. The text file has many lines of ASCII text. Then it finds words out of them (space/tab delimiter). It has to neglect any punctuation symbol in the file. Then it uses those words to form a combinations as `[word1][word2]` to pass to the hashing function to get a result.

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "string.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "ctype.h"


main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    FILE *fin;
    unsigned int i,k,j=0,m=0;
    char c;
    char *ptr, *p;
    char line_buf[1500];
    char word[75];
    unsigned int line_no = 1;    
    char encrypted_pass[120];//Currently it would support MD5,DES,SHA256,SHA512(max - 104 character encrypted password) 
    char *result;
    char pass_key[120];
    char num[6] = {'0','2','4','8','\0'}; 
    unsigned int words_found = 0,len=0;


    char words[1500][8];       


    fin = fopen(argv[1], "rt");
    if(fin == NULL)
    {
        //Exit if file not found
        printf("Error opening input file,...exiting...\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    //Read lines from the file until end of file
    while(!feof(fin))
    {
        //Initialize a index to point to current character in line buffer
        i=0;
        //Initialize a index to current character to be stored in word string
        k=0;
        //read one line at time, from the file      
        ptr = fgets(line_buf,1500,fin);

        if(ptr == NULL)//End of file has reached,stop reading
        {
            break;
        }   

        if(line_buf[i] == '\n')//End of line has reached,continue to read next line
        {
            continue;
        }


        if(line_no == 1)//This is the line containing encrypted password 
        {
            line_no++;
   //Remove any leading spaces,tabs present in the encrypted password line
            while(isspace((unsigned char)(line_buf[m])))
            {
                 m++;
            }
   strcpy(encrypted_pass,&line_buf[m]);

   //Remove any trailing spaces,tabs present in the encrypted password line
   len = strlen(encrypted_pass);
   while ((len > 0) && (isspace((unsigned char)encrypted_pass[len - 1])))
   {
                encrypted_pass[--len] = 0;
            }

   len = strlen(encrypted_pass);
   if(len == 15)//DES-based algorithm where encryped password is 13 characters 
   {
    if(encrypted_pass[len-2] == '\r')
    {
     encrypted_pass[len-2] = '\0';//for \r\n newline character
    }
   }
   else if(len == 14)//DES-based algorithm where encryped password is 13 characters
   {
    if(encrypted_pass[len-1] == '\n')
    {
     encrypted_pass[len-1] = '\0';//for \n newline character
    }
   }
   else if(len == 36)//MD5-based algorithm where encryped password is 34 characters
   {
    if(encrypted_pass[len-2] == '\r')
    {
     encrypted_pass[len-2] = '\0';//for \r\n newline character
    }
   }
   else if(len == 35)//MD5-based algorithm where encryped password is 34 characters
   {
    if(encrypted_pass[len-1] == '\n')
    {
     encrypted_pass[len-1] = '\0';//for \n newline character
    }
   }
    /*
    else if(len == 63)//SHA256-based algorithm where encryped password is 61 characters
    {
        if(encrypted_pass[len-1] == '\n')
        {
            encrypted_pass[len-1] = '\0';//for \n newline character
        }
    }

    else if(len == 62)//SHA256-based algorithm where encryped password is 61 characters
    {
        if(encrypted_pass[len-1] == '\n')
        {
            encrypted_pass[len-1] = '\0';//for \n newline character
        }
    }
    else if(len == 106)//SHA512-based algorithm where encryped password is 104 characters
    {
        if(encrypted_pass[len-1] == '\n')
        {
            encrypted_pass[len-1] = '\0';//for \n newline character
        }
    }
    else if(len == 105)//SHA512-based algorithm where encryped password is 104 characters
    {
        if(encrypted_pass[len-1] == '\n')
        {
            encrypted_pass[len-1] = '\0';//for \n newline character
        }
    }
    */

   continue;
  }       

  //Parse any leading space/tabs present at start of line
  //while(((line_buf[i] == ' ')||(line_buf[i] == '\t'))&&((line_buf[i+1] == ' ')||(line_buf[i+1] == '\t')))
  while((isspace((unsigned char)(line_buf[i])))&&(isspace((unsigned char)(line_buf[i+1]))))
  {
   i++;
  }
  //while((line_buf[i] == '\t')||(line_buf[i] == ' '))
  while(isspace((unsigned char)(line_buf[i])))
  {
   i++;
  }
        //Parse each character in the current line to construct words from it
        while((c=line_buf[i])!=' ')     
        {
           /*       
           if(line_buf[i] == 0)//End Of File reached
           {  
            break;
           }
           */
            if((c=='(')||(c=='[')||(c=='{'))//neglect these characters
            {
                i++;
                continue;
            }

            //Deduce that a word is found based on these character delimeters
            if((c==',')||(c=='.')||(c==';')||(c=='!')||(c=='?')||(c==')')||(c==']')||(c=='}'))
            {
                i++;
                //Insert a null character to terminate the word string
                word[k] = '\0';
                //Check the length of the word found
                //len = strlen(word);
                len = k;

                //Only those words whose length is less than 7 characters are valid due to restriction on password length(8 chars)
                if(len != 0)
                {   
                    if(len < 7)
                    {
                        //one word found, so increment the counter 
                        words_found++;
                        //convert that word to lower case as password consists of lower case words only
                        //lower_case_str(word);                     
                        for (p = word; *p != '\0'; p++)
                        {                       
                           *p = (char) tolower(*p);
                        }
                        //store the word from word string to the word buffer
                        strcpy(words[j],word);
                        //Point to the next row in the 2D words buffer array for words found in the file
                        j++;
                    }                   
                }
                //reset the index in the word string 
                k=0;
                if(line_buf[i] == '\n')//It is end of current line, go to read next line
                {
                    break;
                }

    //while(((line_buf[i] == ' ')||(line_buf[i] == '\t'))&&((line_buf[i+1] == ' ')||(line_buf[i+1] == '\t')))//there are multiple space characters, so consume them as long as you reach non-space char
    while((isspace((unsigned char)(line_buf[i])))&&(isspace((unsigned char)(line_buf[i+1]))))
    {
     i++;
    }
    //while((line_buf[i] == ' ')||(line_buf[i] == '\t'))
    while(isspace((unsigned char)(line_buf[i])))
    {
     i++;
    }   
    /*
    while(((line_buf[i] == '\t')||(line_buf[i] == ' '))&&((line_buf[i+1] == ' ')||(line_buf[i+1] == '\t')))//there are multiple tabs here, so consume them as long as you reach non-tab char
    {
     i++;
    }

    while((line_buf[i] == '\t')||(line_buf[i] == ' '))
    {
     i++;
    }
    */
                if((line_buf[i] == ' '))//Continue to parse next character
                {
                    i++;
                    if(line_buf[i] == '\n')//It is end of current line, go to read next line
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }               

                continue;//Continue to parse next character
            }
   if(isalpha((unsigned char)(c)))
            {
                //Current character is a valid alphabetic letter, so
                //Store the current character in the word string
                word[k] = c;
    //Point to the next position in the word string
                k++;
            }
            else
            {
                //Current character is not a alphabetic letter, so neglect it
                word[k] = '\0';
            }
            //Point to the next character in the line buffer
            i++;


   if(line_buf[i] == 0)//End Of File reached
   {
    word[k] = '\0';
    //len = strlen(word);
    len = k;
    if(len != 0)
    {     
     if(len < 7)
     {
      words_found++;
      //lower_case_str(word);
      for (p = word; *p != '\0'; p++)
        {                       
           *p = (char) tolower(*p);
        }
      strcpy(words[j],word);
      j++;
     }         
    }

    break;
   }

   if((line_buf[i] == ' ')&&((line_buf[i-1] != '\t')&&(line_buf[i-1] != ' ')&&(isalpha((unsigned char)(line_buf[i-1])))))//A word found, based on space delimiter
   {
    i++;
    word[k] = '\0';
    //len = strlen(word);
    len = k;
    if(len != 0)
    {     
     if(len < 7)
     {
      words_found++;
      //lower_case_str(word);
      for (p = word; *p != '\0'; p++)
        {                       
           *p = (char) tolower(*p);
        }
      strcpy(words[j],word);
      j++;
     }          
    }
    k=0;
   }

   if((line_buf[i] == '\t')&&((line_buf[i-1] != ' ')&&(line_buf[i-1] != '\t')&&(isalpha((unsigned char)(line_buf[i-1])))))//A word found, based on horizontal tab delimiter
   {
    i++;
    word[k] = '\0';
    //len = strlen(word);
    len = k;
    if(len != 0)
    {     
     if(len < 7)
     {
      words_found++;
      //lower_case_str(word);
      for (p = word; *p != '\0'; p++)
        {                       
           *p = (char) tolower(*p);
        }
      strcpy(words[j],word);
      j++;
     }          
    }
    k=0;
   }

   if((line_buf[i] == '-')&&(isalpha((unsigned char)(line_buf[i-1]))))//A word found, based on - delimeter
   {
    i++;
    word[k] = '\0';
    //len = strlen(word);
    len = k;
    if(len != 0)
    {     
     if(len < 7)
     {
      words_found++;
      //lower_case_str(word);
      for (p = word; *p != '\0'; p++)
        {                       
           *p = (char) tolower(*p);
        }
      strcpy(words[j],word);
      j++;
     }
     //strcpy(pass_key,word);
     //puts(pass_key);     
    }
    k=0;
   }

   if((isspace((unsigned char)(line_buf[i])))&&(k>0))
   {
    i++;
    word[k] = '\0';
    //len = strlen(word);
    len = k;
    if(len != 0)
    {     
     if(len < 7)
     {
      words_found++;
      //lower_case_str(word);
      for (p = word; *p != '\0'; p++)
        {                       
           *p = (char) tolower(*p);
        }
      strcpy(words[j],word);
      j++;
     }
     //strcpy(pass_key,word);
     //puts(pass_key);     
    }
    k=0;

   }

   if((ispunct((unsigned char)(line_buf[i-1])))&&(k>0))
   {
    i++;
    word[k] = '\0';
    //len = strlen(word);
    len = k;
    if(len != 0)
    {     
     if(len < 7)
     {
      words_found++;
      //lower_case_str(word);
      for (p = word; *p != '\0'; p++)
        {                       
           *p = (char) tolower(*p);
        }
      strcpy(words[j],word);
      j++;
     }
     //strcpy(pass_key,word);
     //puts(pass_key);     
    }
    k=0;

   }

   //while(((line_buf[i] == ' ')||(line_buf[i] == '\t'))&&((line_buf[i+1] == ' ')||(line_buf[i+1] == '\t')))//there are multiple space characters, so consume them as long as you reach non-space char
   while((isspace((unsigned char)(line_buf[i])))&&(isspace((unsigned char)(line_buf[i+1]))))
   {
       i++;
      }
   //while((line_buf[i] == ' ')||(line_buf[i] == '\t'))
   while(isspace((unsigned char)(line_buf[i])))
   {
    i++;
   } 

   /*
   while(((line_buf[i] == '\t')||(line_buf[i] == ' '))&&((line_buf[i+1] == ' ')||(line_buf[i+1] == '\t')))//there are multiple tabs here, so consume them as long as you reach non-tab char
   {
       i++;
      }

   while((line_buf[i] == '\t')||(line_buf[i] == ' '))
   {
    i++;
   }
   */

            if(line_buf[i] == '\n')//Last character in the current line(newline).
            {
                //Insert a null character to terminate the word string
                word[k] = '\0';
                //Check the length of the word found
                //len = strlen(word);
                len = k;
                //Only those words whose length is less than 7 characters are valid due to restriction on password length(8 chars)
                if(len != 0)
                {                   
                    if(len < 7)
                    {
                        //one word found, so increment the counter
                        words_found++;
                        //convert that word to lower case as password consists of lower case words only
                        //lower_case_str(word);
                        for (p = word; *p != '\0'; p++)
                        {                       
                           *p = (char) tolower(*p);
                        }
                        //store the word from word string to the word buffer
                        strcpy(words[j],word);
                        //Point to the next row in the 2D words buffer array for words found in the file
                        j++;
                    }                               
                }
                break;//go to read next line
            }
            else//in between a word, continue scanning for next character
            {
                continue;//Continue to parse next character
            }
        }       
    }


     //Remove duplicate words
     for (i = 0; i < words_found; i ++)
    {
        j = i + 1;
        while (j < words_found)
        {
            if (strcmp(words[i], words[j]) == 0)
            {
                memmove(words + j, words + (words_found - 1), sizeof(words[0]));
                -- words_found;             
            }
            else
                ++ j;
        }
    }



    for(k=0;k<4;k++)
    {
        //Form all possible combination of 2 words found with a number in between
        for(i=0;i<words_found;i++)
        {
            for(j=i+1;j<words_found;j++)
            {   

                strcpy(pass_key,words[i]);

                strncat(pass_key,(const char*)(&num[k]),1);

                strcat(pass_key,words[j]);
                len = strlen(pass_key);

                if((len >= 5)&&(len <= 8))
                {         


                    result = crypt(pass_key, encrypted_pass);                    

                    if(!strcmp(result,encrypted_pass))
                    {

                        printf("%s\n",pass_key);                        
                        exit(-1);
                    }

                }               


            }
        }
    }

    fclose(fin);

}
```

Comment: The somewhat random indentation of your code makes the structure hard to see.  You may get more reviews quicker if you use consistent indentation (either 2 or 4 characters per indent).

Comment: Did your profiling software tell you where the hot spots are?

Comment: What is your performance goal? Just improvement? 1%, 10% 90% 99%? What is the problem? Have you used a profiler to identify a bottleneck?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First, a note for those who might wonder why I'd help somebody who's apparently trying to build a tool to do dictionary attacks on passwords. The reason is pretty simple: first, there are tools that do the job pretty well already, so this is hardly unleashing anything new on the world. Second, this doesn't seem to allow for salt, which means it's pretty much obsolete anyway (and anybody who doesn't use salt deserves to be broken into in any case). Ultimately it comes down to this: I don't think helping out on this will cause any real reduction in security.

While I suppose I can guess at why you've crammed everything into `main`, I think it's a mistake anyway. On a reasonably modern processor, the overhead of calling a function is *extremely* minimal (to the point of being essentially impossible to even measure, in most cases). At the same time, the size of cache (especially level 1 cache) is limited, so eliminating redundancy can and will help speed by fitting more of your code into the cache.

Other than that, your code seems to have quite a bit of redundancy. For example:

```
if((line_buf[i] == ' ')&&(  

    (line_buf[i-1] != '\t')&&
    (line_buf[i-1] != ' ')&&
    (isalpha((unsigned char)(line_buf[i-1]))))

)
```

Now, let me ask a question: do you think it's possible for `isalpha(x)` to return true, if `x=='\t'` or `x==' '` was true? I'm pretty sure the definition of `isalpha` precludes that possibility, so you can dispense with those tests. All you appear to need is:

```
if(line_buf[i] == ' ') && isalpha((unsigned char)line_buf[i-1]))
```

If you're trying to avoid the "overhead" of calling `isalpha`, be aware that in most C libraries it's implemented as a macro that uses a table lookup, so testing for ' ' and '\t' separately is more likely to be a loss than a gain. Even when/if it's a function, modern processors reduce function call overhead to the point that the extra tests are probably a loss anyway.

You then have code like:

```
  for (p = word; *p != '\0'; p++)
    {                       
       *p = (char) tolower(*p);
    }
  strcpy(words[j],word);
```

This is quite inefficient. First it walks through the code modifying it in place, then it copies the modified data to a new location. You should be able to improve speed by combining the two:

```
for (i=0; p[i]; i++)
    words[j][i] = tolower(p[i]);
words[j][i] = '\0';
```

Looking at a slightly higher level, you seem to care very little about the overall line structure of the input, and are interested primarily (exclusively?) in words. That being the case, you'd probably be better off *not* reading a line at a time. The result would be simpler, and probably faster as well. For example, you have a pretty big block of code to read the encrypted/hashed password and eliminate leading/trailing white space:

```
        if(line_no == 1)//This is the line containing encrypted password 
        {
            line_no++;
   //Remove any leading spaces,tabs present in the encrypted password line
            while(isspace((unsigned char)(line_buf[m])))
            {
                 m++;
            }
   strcpy(encrypted_pass,&line_buf[m]);

   //Remove any trailing spaces,tabs present in the encrypted password line
   len = strlen(encrypted_pass);
   while ((len > 0) && (isspace((unsigned char)encrypted_pass[len - 1])))
   {
                encrypted_pass[--len] = 0;
            }

   len = strlen(encrypted_pass);
   if(len == 15)//DES-based algorithm where encryped password is 13 characters 
   {
    if(encrypted_pass[len-2] == '\r')
    {
     encrypted_pass[len-2] = '\0';//for \r\n newline character
    }
   }
   else if(len == 14)//DES-based algorithm where encryped password is 13 characters
   {
    if(encrypted_pass[len-1] == '\n')
    {
     encrypted_pass[len-1] = '\0';//for \n newline character
    }
   }
   else if(len == 36)//MD5-based algorithm where encryped password is 34 characters
   {
    if(encrypted_pass[len-2] == '\r')
    {
     encrypted_pass[len-2] = '\0';//for \r\n newline character
    }
   }
   else if(len == 35)//MD5-based algorithm where encryped password is 34 characters
   {
    if(encrypted_pass[len-1] == '\n')
    {
     encrypted_pass[len-1] = '\0';//for \n newline character
    }
   }
```

It appears that this entire block of code works our roughly equivalent to:

```
fscanf(" %119[^ \r\n]", encrypted_pass);
```

I've changed the maximum length to 119 based on the buffer length you provided. If you prefer to limit it to 34, that's pretty easy to handle as well. I'd note, however, that not only is this dramatically *shorter*, but probably faster as well -- for example, your code copies data you don't really want, then walks through all that data to find the length, truncates some of it, walks through to find the length *again*, and redundantly attempts to truncate the same data again (perhaps you didn't realize that `'\r'` and `'\n'` are classified as white space, at least in the "C" locale?) Using `fscanf`, you read (only) the data you care about, and you're done.

Similarly, most of the rest of your code for reading words from the file can probably be collapsed down to a single call to `fscanf` with an appropriate conversion. I haven't looked at all of it in sufficient detail to be sure of the exact conversion, but it looks like `%7[A-Za-z]` is somewhere in the ballpark of a reasonable start.

Ultimately, however, all of this is pretty much a fart in a hurricane as far as effect on speed goes. You can scan and copy buffers dozens of extra times, and the time it takes will still be down in the noise level compared to what it takes to copy that data from the disk drive into memory. There are really two places you can gain enough to notice:

1. More efficient disk transfers
2. parallel processing in the dictionary attack

Note that the two aren't mutually exclusive, but both generally require non-portable code (e.g., on Linux, you'd probably use `mmap`, but on Windows `CreateFile` and `ReadFile` to read the data).

At a guess, the latter is the part that's taking the most time, and also the place you stand the best chance of improving speed enough to care much about.

Comment: @Jerry - Thanks for comments. Yes I am trying to learn cryptography libraries and crypt seemed to be the simplest to start. Actually after posting here, I have cleaned up many redundant if checks, incorporated library functions straightway in my code. You review inputs were good. I will do thsoe changes as well. Thanks really for the last two bits of input - improving disk transfer and exploiting parallelism in the core function. Here do you mean using threads or you mean some kind of data parallelism  by writing SIMD code  if underlying processor has multicores and/or SIMD?

Comment: @goldenmean: the primary place to use SIMD code would be in the implementation of the hash function itself. The main thing you want to do is threading to do more than one hash at a time.

Comment: +1 This is a brilliant answer, from the first paragraph (which made me chuckle) right to the end. Superb!